# Managed package checkbox disabled - SalesForce

Tags: managed-package, unmanaged-package

Why is the check-box is disabled when creating a `Managed package`

[image]

Comment: Did you set up a namespace? Is there already a managed package in the org?

Comment: yes I have setup a namespace and also there is already a managed packaged and i wanted to create a another one, i'm not sure how the packages works and i have no idea; if it allows you to install more then one package

Comment: You cannot have two managed packages for the same namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have more than one managed package for the same namespace

> The developer settings in a Developer Edition organization allow you
>   to create a single managed package, upload that package to the
>   AppExchange, allowing other users to install and upgrade the package
>   in their organization. After configuring your developer settings the
>   first time, you can no longer modify them. Regardless of the developer
>   settings, you can always create an unlimited number of unmanaged
>   packages.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=configure_developer_settings.htm&language=en_US

Comment: so what do i need to do? edit the existing package and add-on ?

Comment: It depends on your use case and model. You could update the existing package, or create a new package in another org "Extension Package" that you install the first package in that new org and build off of it. The extension package would be dependent on the original package being installed

Comment: is that consider to be best practice if I delete the existing package and create a new one?

Comment: No one said to delete the existing package - That could be catostrophic. Info on extension packages - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=publish_extensions.htm&language=en

Comment: I have already installed a Managed Package in my org and added few custom objects/classes/pages and you said it can be update the existing package will that work in my scenario?

Comment: I cannot answer that question as it is not clear enough. Simply, the package owner can modify and add to their managed package. You should read up on packaging, do a google search for "Salesforce Managed Packages" and begin your education

Comment: Also, I believe it is time to mark this as answered as the discussion is deviating significantly from your original question

Comment: no problem will create a new question but since you have mentioned in your answer i was trying to clearly the point you raised, i am not changing my question or adding more to it :)

Comment: Correct. But you said "update the existing package will that work in my scenario" just be aware that that is not specific enough. there is A LOT to consider....

Comment: i have posted a new question here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91840/updating-an-existing-managed-package-salesforce