# Updating an existing Managed package - SalesForce

Tags: managed-package, unmanaged-package

I have Managed package installed in my org and we have added more new custom objects/classes/pages etc... I know that SF does not allow to have more then one managed package so my question is:

What is the best way handle this situation 
I do not like of carrying extension because it will always depend on the managed package and I'm leaning towards more re-create all the objects I have in my managed package and then drop the managed package and create a fresh new package?

PS: nothing is in production yet all in the sandbox

Comment: What do you mean by "SF does not allow to have more then one managed package"? Do you have a link to the limit you are referring to here?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=configure_developer_settings.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic example:

1. You have a managed package created and released
2. You add an object / field / code, etc to the dev org where the managed package is created
3. You can add all of that to the managed package and release a new version by

   - Clicking the "Developing xxxxx" link in the top right corner
   - Ensure the new objects are listed as a part of the package, if they are not click the "Add" button
   - When you are done click the "Upload" button and select the appropriate options

Once uploaded you can install the updated package into the client orgs and they will contain the new data...

This is the most basic example and there is a lot to consider...

- Are the updates part of a feature that clients will pay more for
- Security implications (New fields on existing objects / new objects) may not have the FLS updated in the client org
- The ability to delete items added is limited, so do not just add stuff to the package, be purposeful

Anyone feel free to add to this answer to add other caveats.

Comment: Eric: I know how to create a package but my question is different then what you have answered, pleas read the last part of my question

Comment: My answer is applicable to your question, I think you are misunderstanding the capabilities of a managed package or are not clearly stating what you are trying to do. It does not matter if the client or you installed the package in their sandbox or production. that is irrelevant. You do NOT need to drop the managed package you created just to add to it